# Binding Image to ComboBox.ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, image, data-binding, combobox, imagesource

I'm attempting what I thought is some fairly simple binding. I'm binding a Collection of Character Objects to my ComboBox. To display the list of characters in the combobox, I'm using the combobox.itemtemplate where I display the character Name, Level, and Image.

I can display the Character Name and Level, but not the image. I believe I am binding the image to the xaml correctly. Any idea what I'm missing?

xaml

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="Character_ComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="328" Height="25">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Width="50" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Width="50" Text="{Binding Level}"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding dependaImage}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
    public ObservableCollection<Character> squad_members = new ObservableCollection<Character>();
    public Image depImage;
    public Image dependaImage 
    {
        get 
        {
            Image designate = new Image();
            BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("character1.png", UriKind.Relative));
            designate.Source = bmi;

            return designate;
        } 
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        squad_members.Add(new Character() { Name = "Wacken", Level = 8, Character_Class = CharacterClass.Mage, _Gender = Gender.Male, Strength = 6, Intelligence = 9, Dexterity = 3, Gold = 1255, Inventory = new ObservableCollection<Item>() { new Item("Gerrund Wand", "Magical Direction", 656, "Witcher Magical Wand", true ), new Item("Velcro Whip", "Whips your face off", 12, "Annoying as hell", true ), new Item("Invisibility Cloak", "Invisibility", 900, "Cloak of Invisibility", true)}});
        squad_members.Add(new Character() { Name = "Vrigun", Level = 4, Character_Class = CharacterClass.Mage, _Gender = Gender.Female, Strength = 3, Intelligence = 10, Dexterity = 1, Gold = 2055, Inventory = new ObservableCollection<Item>() { new Item("Satanic Girdings", "Demonic Protection", 6660, "Clothing protects user from attack", true ), new Item("Viper Staff", "Poisons Enemy Resolve", 860, "Bites and Kills Everything", true ), new Item("Baal Mask", "Infects enemy mind", 6660, "Possesses User's Opponents", false ) }});

        Binding comboBinding = new Binding();
        comboBinding.Source = squad_members;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(Character_ComboBox, ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, comboBinding);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the `Source` property to an `Image`.. try this

```
public ImageSource depImage;
public ImageSource dependaImage 
{
    get 
    {
        if( depImage == null )
            {
                depImage= new BitmapImage( new Uri( "character1.png", UriKind.Relative ) );
            }
            return depImage;
    } 
}
```

And, your `Character` class should have this property.

Comment: is _imageSource of type Image in this case? or is it something else?

Comment: gotcha. The image still won't bind inside the combobox though.

Comment: Move the ImageSource property to the Character class

Comment: Shouldn't it be able to bind from where it is right now? It should be able to bind from where it is. (This is a bit of a contrived scenario -- in current code I'm just attempting to bind one image to every combobox character representation)

Comment: The context for the template would come from the ItemsSource of the ComboBox, which is not the current place, which instead each Item in your Character s collection..

Comment: @user2453973 as @bit saying `{Binding dependaImage}` means `Character.dependaImage` in your case.